# Linux boot: Can I prevent the loading of a module using a boot parameter?

Tags: boot, kernel, grub

I know that I can blacklist a module in `/etc/modprobe.conf` or `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`, but I have a nasty module which loads before the filesystems are mounted (except /boot of course), so I assume, `/etc` will not yet be read by then.

**Can I prevent a module from loading using a kernel boot parameter?**
(I'm using GRUB)

Or are there other ways to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules that load that early in the boot sequence are built into the initramfs; it seems likely that you can run `update-initramfs -c -k your_kernel_version` to ensure that the blacklisted module isn't loaded in that initramfs image.

Comment: *I don't actually use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This Ubuntu site has a nice breakdown of options:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common%20Boot%20Options

While there aren't any ways to tell the kernel to not load a module at boot time, you can get in the way later on down the road. Take a look at the break= optionss, that change initrd behavior. If you don't know the exact module, you can perhaps use these to further isolate it.